Cannot mount WD Elements external drive, unsure if corrupted or fixable
I finished doing regular backup of data via borg into my WD Elements external hard drive, and left it plugged in. The spinning sound persisted for a while, then suddenly stopped.
Tried to access drive, but cannot mount it. I usually do this via ranger-fm and udisksctl – see here  – the error that comes up is:
Error mounting /dev/sdb1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /run/media/nonreligious/Elements: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

The error I get from udiskie-mount /dev/sdb1 /run/media/nonreligious/Elements is
failed to add /run/media/nonreligious/Elements/: no device found owning "/run/media/nonreligious/Elements/"
failed to mount /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /run/media/nonreligious/Elements: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Doing sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /run/media/nonreligious/Elements is
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 3).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.

Powering the disk off, unplugging it and re-plugging it does not help.
Running lsblk gives:
sdb                                    8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdb1                                 8:17   0 931.5G  0 part

Running lsblk --fs (for filesystem details) gives:
sdb
└─sdb1   ntfs         Elements 8A023C4D023C410D

Running sudo fdisk -l gives:
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.48 GiB, 1000170586112 bytes, 1953458176 sectors
Disk model: Elements 25A2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B22248D2-DE5B-43FC-8497-5A32AA24B372

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 1953456127 1953454080 931.5G Microsoft basic data

Running sudo fsck /dev/sdb gives (sudo fsck /dev/sdb1 just gives the first line of the following):
fsck from util-linux 2.39.3
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

/dev/sdb contains `DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,255,63), startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors, extended partition table (last)' data

I'm not 100% sure I remember, but I thought that my drive was formatted as EXT4, not NTFS.
So … can I recover my data? What should I do? I've seen similar posts that suggested using ntfsfix, but I'm not sure my drive is NTFS formatted. Another post suggested using testdisk. I'd appreciate any suggestions or comments.

You appear to be using a disk formatted as NTFS. Get a Windows machine to check and repair the filesystem

@ChrisDavies Thanks -- I found a machine to plug it into and found that it is still readable, but Windows asks to "check" it as you say -- there's no (major) chance of data loss if I do that, right?

You will need to check and fix the filesystem. The only time I caution against this is when a disk is failing with read/write errors. In this situation the correct thing is to clone the disk with something like ddrescue and then fix a copy of the clone

@ChrisDavies Thanks, I ran the repair utility that was
suggested when I plugged the drive into Windows 11, and it ran in less than 10 seconds. It seemed to do the trick, as I was able to mount the drive on my Linux machine afterwards without any problems.

As @ChrisDavies suggested, I plugged the drive into a Windows machine and ran the repair utility that popped up. It ran quickly, and afterwards I was able to mount the drive on my Linux machine without any issues.
